# Dependency issues with Dynamic Framework iOS

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, static-libraries, dynamic-library

In my project I am using cocoa pods as dependency manager. I have added a static framework as my pod dependency (say Framework A).

Another framework (say Framework B) which is dynamic framework is embedded to my project.(It is not a pod dependency, directly linked and embedded with Xcode project.) The framework B has pod dependency of the Framework A which is a static framework and also added as a dependency to my main project.

In my framework B project, I have not chosen to embed the Framework A library.

Even though Framework A is not embedded to Framework B, all the calls to Framework A methods are not directed to the main project's dependency, instead it is directed like Framework A is part of Framework B and break points are not hit to the Framework A methods which is added as pod dependency.

My question is that,  as the Framework A is static framework, even though it is not embeded, will it be copied as a dependency in compile time when Framework B is built ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you build an app or dynamic framework with a static dependency, all of the code of the static dependency is linked into the binary that is in the bundle. There is no need to also include the static framework as a resource that will be loaded at runtime.

This is my understanding of what you have

```
App
- Framework A (statically linked)
- Framework B (dynamic)
  - Framework A (statically linked)
```

If this is so, B has its own copy of A.  Neither the app nor Framework B will look for Framework at runtime in the app bundle because they have a copy of the parts they need inside their own binary.

Comment: Yes your understanding is correct. So in this case always Framework B contains the copy of Framework A and it is not possible to build Framework B with out Framework A. Am I Right ?

Comment: If everyone used A dynamically, B would use the app’s A

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: okay. Thank you. What I am trying to accomplish is A should be an independent framework to be integrated in main App and all other frameworks integrated to App should able to use the Framework A

Comment: Use A dynamically then.

Comment: The framework A is having other dynamic dependencies managed by pod. So if A is dynamic, all the pod dependencies should be specified from the project scope right  or how such dependencies can be managed in an effective way ?. Does it have any performance impact? If A is static, all its dynamic dependencies would be copied inside A itself . Again if we embed the static framework A into another dynamic framework (say C) which is a wrapper to A , all the dependencies of A will be inside the dynamic framework C and it can be integrated separately. Does it sounds okay ?

Comment: When you use a framework dynamically in a framework (1) nothing is copied into the wrapper framework (2) it will look for the framework at runtime (3) "Does it have performance impact" it could -- if you have excessive dynamic frameworks (e.g. 100s) then startup time will be super slow (maybe not fast enough for iOS and you'll be killed).  You need to check -- it's probably fine (I barely notice it on an app with dozens, but we have brought the number down with some static usage). If you have a start up problem, then solve it -- if you don't -- keep it simple

Comment: Thank you very much!